# Обойти медленный цикл For

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, for

```py
for x in range(0,2048):     
        filepath1=newpath +str(x)+suffix
        filein = open(filepath1, mode='rb');
        bufRead=filein.read();filein.close()
        err=0
        for i in range(Size):           # Slow
                if  bufRead[i] != num : # Slow
                        err=err+1       # Slow
        if err != 0:
            print(filepath1,"errorREAD",err)
            input()
        else  :print(filepath1,"errorREAD",err)
```

Очень медленно выполняется цикл For
по прикидкам должно быть не менее  50 млн проходов за секунду
для 3ГГц процессора .наблюдается на 2 порядка меньше
Как сравнить  ускоренно  весь массив загруженный из файла  с константой    ?

Answer (score 0):

Если `bufRead` - список (судя по всему, это так), то можно использовать метод count(), который в несколько раз быстрее, чем проход по списку:

```
# считаем количество элементов num в списке и вычитаем из общего количества
err = len(bufRead) - bufRead.count(num)
```

Сравнение цикла `for` и `.count()`:

```
import time

buf = [1,2,3,4,5,34,5,2,3,3,42,3,4,23,4,254]*100

#Solution 1 - Faster
n = 0
start = time.monotonic()
while n < 100000:
    count = 0
    for element in buf:
        if element == 5:
            count += 1
    n += 1
end = time.monotonic()
print(count)
print('Длительность for: {}'.format(end - start))

n = 0
start = time.monotonic()
while n < 100000:
    count = buf.count(5)
    n += 1
end = time.monotonic()
print (count)
print('Длительность count(): {}'.format(end - start))
```

Результат:

```
200
Длительность for: 9.89000000001397
200
Длительность count(): 2.3249999999970896
```

В данном примере `count()` примерно в 4 раза быстрее.

Comment: Как видно из кода, bufRead это таки bytes (к счастью, у него тоже есть count)

Comment: в моем варианте  накапливается количество несовпадений а в вашем количество совпадений

Comment: Посмотрите первый фрагмент кода, который до сравнения.

Comment: подскажите решение через numpy.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
X = 100000000
R = list(range(X))
bufRead = [b'1']*X

# index
(err, num) = (0, b'2')
t = time.monotonic()
for i in R:
    if bufRead[i] != num:
        err += 1
print(time.monotonic() - t)  # 30.3 сек

# iter
(err, num) = (0, b'2')
t = time.monotonic()
for e in bufRead:
    if e != num:
        err += 1
print(time.monotonic() - t)  # 21.0 сек

# len
(err, num) = (0, b'2')
t = time.monotonic()
err = len([e for e in bufRead if e != num])
print(time.monotonic() - t)  # 17.7 сек

# filter len
(err, num) = (0, b'1')
t = time.monotonic()
err = (X - len(list(filter(num.__eq__, bufRead))))  # 15.6 сек
print(time.monotonic() - t)
```

Comment: Сравните теперь с ``err = len(bufRead) - bufRead.count(b'1')``